# Zend Navigation Find Page and Render Menu with its Subpages

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, acl, findby

I am putting together a Zend Navigation for a site with 4 different levels of access: Guest, Member1, Member2, and Admin.

My navigation XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <nav>
        <default>
            <label>Home</label>
            <controller>index</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>index</resource>
            <privilege>index</privilege>

            <pages>
                <home>
                    ...
                </home>
                <signin>
                    ...
                </signin>
                <signup>
                    ...
                </signup>
            </pages>
        </default>

        <member1>
            <label>Member1 Main</label>
            <controller>member1</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>member1</resource>
            <privilege>index</privilege>

            <pages>
                <dashboard>
                    ...
                </dashboard>
                <settings>
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <controller>auth</controller>
                    <action>editpassword</action>
                    <resource>auth</resource>
                    <privilege>editpassword</privilege>
                    <class>settings</class>
                    <title>User settings</title>

                    <pages>
                        <account>
                            ...
                        </account>
                        <logout>
                            ...
                        </logout>
                    </pages>
                </settings>
            </pages>
        </member1>

        <member2>
            <label>Member2 Main</label>
            <controller>member2</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>member2</resource>
            <privilege>index</privilege>

            <pages>
                <dashboard>
                    ...
                </dashboard>
                <profile>
                    ...
                </profile>
                <settings>
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <controller>auth</controller>
                    <action>editpassword</action>
                    <resource>auth</resource>
                    <privilege>editpassword</privilege>
                    <class>settings</class>

                    <pages>
                        <account>
                            ...
                        </account>
                        <logout>
                            ...
                        </logout>
                    </pages>
                </settings>
            </pages>
        </member2>

        <admin>
            <label>Dashboard</label>
            <controller>admin</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>admin</resource>
            <privilege>index</privilege>

            <pages>
                <dashboard>
                    ...
                </dashboard>
                <logout>
                    ...
                </logout>
            </pages>
        </admin>

    </nav>
</config>
```

Since I am using submenus and want consistency for top menu, I want to use a Zend's **findBy** feature to locate current user's status and display that menu. This is done as such:

```
if ( $this->user ) {
    $submenu = $this->navigation()->findOneByLabel('Member1 Main');
    $options = array(
        'ulClass'               => 'navigation',
        'renderParents'         => true,
        'minDepth'              => null,
        'maxDepth'              => null
    );
    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($submenu, $options);
} else {
    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('navigation')->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->setMinDepth(1)->setMaxDepth(1);
}
```

My Bootstrap bit for Nav is pretty generic and looks like this:

```
function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();

    $navConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($navConfig);

    $front     = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $myPlagin  = $front->getPlugin('My_Controller_Plugin_Acl');

    $view->navigation($navigation)->setAcl($myPlagin->getMyAcl())
                                 ->setRole($myPlagin->getMyUserRole());
}
```

Now, I can get the "Member1 Main" page to appear, but it only shows that one page, but what I need to render is that page's whole submenu. It seems that **findOneByLabel** only looks up that particular page only and not its descendants. Is there a way to pull the whole submenu?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your expected result? I'm not sure what is it you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use **findAllByLabel** to get the expected result. Thanks @RockyFord